# Image Texture Didn't Apply to Model

Tags: texturing, materials, image

Image Texture Didn't Apply in Model and when i try apply it's look like that

Here is the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SvSTPzqZeT0I65Z2vVyeBkcGPSM2FFyK/view?usp=sharing

Here is the texture:

[image: texture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objects have not been unwrapped, plus you didn't select the good image in the *Image Texture* node of your material.